# How to iterate over columns in a .csv with Panda and return a value to a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a .csv I am trying to analyze with Pandas.
I want to iterate over the columns and look for a cell value between a certain value (eg: between 5 and 8). And if it finds one, i want it to add that value to a new list.
I've read the .csv into Python with a Panda.
I think i need to use this...

for index, row in df.iterrows():

but cannot figure out the next steps.
Thank you!

Comment: Is iterating over columns important? Wouldn't it be easier to simply grab all values between 5 and 8?

Comment: i guess it doesn't need to iterate across columns. if it can interrogate the entire .csv and find all the numbers in a range and then add those to a list, that'd work too!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use any Pandas methods that start with *iter*, they are incredibly slow compared to vectorized operations.

To get all values between 5 and 8 from a dataframe you can do the following:

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i for i in range(10)], 'b':[i for i in range(6, 16)]})  

x = df.values  # Get values as a numpy array
res = x[(x > 5) & (x < 8)]

Out:  array([6, 7, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
```